# Adding a step/steps to angular-multi-step-form on button click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using https://github.com/troch/angular-multi-step-form to build a multi step form in AngularJS but having a little trouble dynamically adding steps to the directive.

Here is the basic setup I have:

```
<multi-step-container steps="sections" on-finish="finish($getActiveStep())" initial-step="step" search-id="'step'">
        <step-container></step-container>
<multi-step-container>
```

the steps attribute is what determines the amount of steps to show, this is just a simple array of steps set in $scope.

This works great for when there is a fixed number of steps, however, in my use case I need to add additional steps dynamically when the clicks on a button within my form.

I thought that this would be just a simple case of using `$scope.sections.push(section)` to add to the array but apparently this doesn't work. There is a couple of issues around this in the repo but all have been closed with little/no explanation on how to work around this.

Any ideas or things I can try out?

Comment: Have you tried setting $scopes.sections to a new reference?
So it could be a problem with $watch

Comment: how would I go about that?

Comment: $scope.sections.push(section); //same as before
$scope.sections = $scope.sections.slice(); //will make a array and perhaps solve the problem, if it is a problem with $watch.

Comment: Did it work or is there an other problem?

Comment: Sorry but this didnt seem to work, here is some code that may/may not help, essentially I am looping though each of the question goto's and running this which returns a nicely formatted array that I was just planning on appending to the existing array: ```Section.generateStepFromSection(dependentSection).then(function(response) {
        $scope.sections.push(response);
        // $scope.sections = $scope.sections.slice();
       });```

Comment: Ok I am sorry. 
What happens in Section.generateStepFromSection or whats in the response? How is the $scope.sections structured? 
With out that information I couldn't reproduce the problem.

Comment: So all the `Section.generateStepFromSection` does is return an array. It's literally just a mapping function. I can see that the `$scope.sections.push(response) is actually having the desired effect but it seems that the directive isn't picking it up :(

Comment: Recently I tried it myself, and it is true, the steps must be set at the beginning and can't be changed. It seems like the multistepcontainer makes a deep copy from the original steps. As a result further actions won't influence them. 

A new issue was already created. 
https://github.com/troch/angular-multi-step-form/issues/55